# ANDROID: MVVM + Retrofit: How and where shall I retrieve JSON Object List from JSON object array?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have set up everything for calls and I am getting list with 0 size. After some research, I realized that I was trying to retrieve JSON objects, meanwhile the root of my response.body is a JSON array. I have checked the web, it seems like I should add a wrapper to my "Task" (which is my model) , do the calls with a List. 
But I do not understand exactly how shall I do it.
Where shall I get the JSON array and where and how exactly shall I parse JSON Object array root to list of JSON objects so that I can continue with binding in recycler view.

Model:

```
public class Task {
@SerializedName("taskId")
@Expose
private int taskId;

private int requestId;

private int currentEventId;

private int technicianId;

private int supervisorId;

private String status;

@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
@Nullable
private String itemCategory;


@SerializedName("brand")
@Expose
@Nullable
private String itemBrand;


@SerializedName("model")
@Expose
@Nullable
private String itemModel;


@SerializedName("series")
@Expose
@Nullable
private String itemSeria;

@SerializedName("series")
@Expose
@Nullable
private String address;

private String requestIndicator;
private String requestCode;
private String requestName;
private String requestCompanyLogo;

@SerializedName("assignDate")
@Expose
private String assignDate;

@SerializedName("assignDate")
@Expose
private String assignTime;

private List<Task> tasks = null;


public int getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public int getRequestId() {
    return requestId;
}

public void setRequestId(int requestId) {
    this.requestId = requestId;
}

public int getCurrentEventId() {
    return currentEventId;
}

public void setCurrentEventId(int currentEventId) {
    this.currentEventId = currentEventId;
}

public int getTechnicianId() {
    return technicianId;
}

public void setTechnicianId(int technicianId) {
    this.technicianId = technicianId;
}

public int getSupervisorId() {
    return supervisorId;
}

public void setSupervisorId(int supervisorId) {
    this.supervisorId = supervisorId;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getAssignDate() {
    return assignDate;
}

public void setAssignDate(String assignDate) {
    this.assignDate = assignDate;
}

public String getRequestName() {
    return requestName;
}

public void setRequestName(String requestName) {
    this.requestName = requestName;
}

public String getItemCategory() {
    return itemCategory;
}

public void setItemCategory(String itemCategory) {
    this.itemCategory = itemCategory;
}

public String getItemBrand() {
    return itemBrand;
}

public void setItemBrand(String itemBrand) {
    this.itemBrand = itemBrand;
}

public String getItemModel() {
    return itemModel;
}

public void setItemModel(String itemModel) {
    this.itemModel = itemModel;
}

public String getItemSeria() {
    return itemSeria;
}

public void setItemSeria(String itemSeria) {
    this.itemSeria = itemSeria;
}

public String getRequestIndicator() {
    return requestIndicator;
}

public void setRequestIndicator(String requestIndicator) {
    this.requestIndicator = requestIndicator;
}

public String getRequestCode() {
    return requestCode;
}

public void setRequestCode(String requestCode) {
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
}

public String getRequestCompanyLogo() {
    return requestCompanyLogo;
}

public void setRequestCompanyLogo(String requestCompanyLogo) {
    this.requestCompanyLogo = requestCompanyLogo;
}

public String getAssignTime() {
    return assignTime;
}

public void setAssignTime(String assignTime) {
    this.assignTime = assignTime;
}

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
}
```

}

Webservice:

```
public interface TaskWebService {
@GET("tasks/new")
Call<List<Task>> getTasks(@Query("count") int count, @Query("pageNumber") int pageNumber, @Query("taskStatus") String taskStatus, @Header("token") String token);
```

}

RetrofitNetworkService:

```
public class RetrofitNetworkService {

private static final String BASE_URL = "bla bla bla";


private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

TaskRepository:

```
public class TaskRepo {

private static TaskRepo taskRepo;
private static TaskWebService taskWebService;

private TaskRepo() {
    taskWebService = 
RetrofitNetworkService.createService(TaskWebService.class);
}

public static TaskRepo getInstance() {
    if (taskRepo == null) {
        taskRepo = new TaskRepo();
    }
    return taskRepo;
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Task>> getTasks(int count, int pageNumber, String taskStatus, String token) {

    final MutableLiveData<List<Task>> allTasks = new MutableLiveData<>();

    taskWebService.getTasks(count, pageNumber, taskStatus, token).enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                allTasks.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
            allTasks.setValue(null);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return allTasks;
}
```

}

ViewModel:

public class ViewModelTask extends ViewModel {

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Task>> allTasks = new MutableLiveData<>();
private TaskRepo taskRepo;

public void initialize() {
    if (allTasks != null) {
        return;
    }
    taskRepo = TaskRepo.getInstance();
    allTasks = taskRepo.getTasks(15, 0, "", ""code);
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
    return allTasks;
}
```

}

View:

public class FragmentTabAll extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView taskRecyclerView;
private int adapterType;
private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewModelTask viewModelTask;
private TaskAdapter taskAdapter;


public FragmentTabAll(int adapterType) {
    this.adapterType = adapterType;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_all, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    taskRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_cardview);
    taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(getActivity());
    checkAdapterType();
}

private void checkAdapterType() {
    if (adapterType == Utils.TASK_ADAPTER) {
        taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        viewModelTask = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelTask.class);
        viewModelTask.initialize();
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

        viewModelTask.getAllTasks().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Task>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {
                taskList.addAll(tasks);
                taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
                taskAdapter.setTaskList(taskList);
            }
        });
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

    } else if (adapterType == Utils.REQUEST_ADAPTER) {
        taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RequestAdapter(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

}

I am expecting to get a recycler view full of tasks (databinding of item works when I populate the list manually), but when I try to implement the calls I get an empty list.

Comment: Just saying: you put up a ton of code. Few people will be willing to go through all of that to do your debugging for you. See [mcve] and think if there aren't ways to significantly reduce the amount of information you expect people to digest in order to *help* you.

Comment: I was thinking I have put less than necessary:D thanks anyway, will wait a little bit and then maybe follow your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer, posting here in case someone else runs into the same issue.
In ViewModel I had the following line:

private MutableLiveData> allTasks = new MutableLiveData<>();

Initializing allTasks gave a null value to it, hence, in the below if statement
it was always returning and not getting the List from TaskRepo, hence, I was getting null in the list that I get in UI.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't debug your code, but seeing it I think the problem is here:

```
 public MutableLiveData<List<Task>> getTasks(int count, int pageNumber, String taskStatus, String token) {

        final MutableLiveData<List<Task>> allTasks = new MutableLiveData<>();

        taskWebService.getTasks(count, pageNumber, taskStatus, token).enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    allTasks.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
                allTasks.setValue(null);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return allTasks;
    }
```

getTasks is an asynchronous call, because you're returning Call from your interface (if you want a syncronous behaviour, you might want reutnr an List or whatever), so allTasks LiveData is not waiting for the response, and just returning a empty LiveData.

I suggest you to work with callbacks, just change the return to void, and pass an callback on parameter like:

```
public void getTasks(int count, int pageNumber, String taskStatus, String token, OnCompleteCallback onComplete) {


        taskWebService.getTasks(count, pageNumber, taskStatus, token).enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    onComplete.done(response.body())
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
                onComplete.done(null)
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, what you should do is to change your viewmodel to publish you data, so your activity/fragment can receive your changes

```
allTasks = taskRepo.getTasks(15, 0, "", ""code, new OnCompleteCallback<>{
     @Override
     void done(List<Tasks> mListTasks){
          if (mListTasks != null){
            allTasks.postValue(mListTaks)
          }
     }
});
```

at this point, your activity/fragment must be observing for alltasks, then you do whatever you need.
Hope this helps you